# Why does Eigenvalues work for a matrix $\{M\}$ but not $\{\{M\}\}$?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

which I'll call `mat`. In a blur of human error, I computed the eigenvalues of `mat` with an extra set of curly braces surrounding it. To my surprise, this still gave me the anticipated result.

```
In[166]:= Eigenvalues[mat]
          Eigenvalues[{mat}]

Out[166]= {1/2 (5 + Sqrt[33]), 1/2 (5 - Sqrt[33])}

Out[167]= {1/2 (5 + Sqrt[33]), 1/2 (5 - Sqrt[33])}
```

I checked to see if this also happens if I were to add yet another set of braces to `{mat}`, but this is not the case.

```
In[168]:= Eigenvalues[{{mat}}]

During evaluation of In[168]:= Eigenvalues::matsq: Argument {{{{1,2},{3,4}}}} at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix. >>

Out[168]= Eigenvalues[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}}]
```

Why is it that I can compute the eigenvalues of `mat` and `{mat}`, but not `{{mat}}`?

Judging by the documentation, my best guess is that `Eigenvalues` is computing the eigenvalues for `mat` with respect to some matrix, *but I didn't specify one*. What's going on here?

Comment: Prolly a holdover from the syntax for matrix pencils, but that one needs a list of *two* matrices and not just one.